# Replace kendo button with icon

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

I would like to replace whole kendo custom button with font awesome icon.

here is my code

```
                  column.Command(command => { command.Edit().Text("<i class='fa fa-history' data-placement='top' style = 'margin-left:-15px;font-size:16px;'></i>"); }).Width(40).Title("<center>History</center>").HtmlAttributes(new { title = "Ticket History" });
```

Comment: What version of Kendo are you using? Its hard to tell from one single line of code if all the rest of your code is correct. I've added font awesome icons to my grids before, its pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is put css on your button and put the alpha of your background color and border color to 0. This will display only the span inside the button and the button won't be visible but will still act like a button.